# Why the use of porta in stead of trisa functions works in a 16F84?

Tags: pic

Still learning PIC programming.

I came accros the following operational code as shown in the top part of the listing. In this code the PORT registers are used during initialisation and the TRIS registers react. I dont understand why this works and can not figure out why? Whith what I have learned sofar this code should not be working correctly.

The second part of the code contains the changes I made.

Instead of the PORT registers I use the TRIS registers during initialisation.
With what I have learned sofar my code should be correct.

I have used the MPLAB simulator during the process. The register information commes from the Special Functions Register.

```
INIT       

            MOVLW H'C0'                ; PB6 & PB7 inputs all others outputs
            MOVWF PORTB                ;  TRISB is changing. WHY?
            MOVLW H'10'                ; Port RA4 input, others outputs
            MOVWF PORTA                ;  TRISA is changing. WHY? 
            MOVLW H'03'                ; prescaler on TMR0 and 1:16
            OPTION                     
            MOVLW H'A0'                ; GIE & T0IE set T0IF cleared
            MOVWF INTCON               
            MOVLW H'F4'                ; initialize INTCNT
            MOVWF INTCNT               
            MOVLW H'06'                ; initialize FUDGE
            MOVWF FUDGE                
            CLRF OFFSET                ; initialize OFFSET
            RETURN
```

; After reading the manuals some changes seem to be required for proper initialisation

```
INIT        BSF   STATUS,RP0            ;Change to Bank1 
            MOVLW B'11000000'          ; PB6 & PB7 inputs all others outputs
            MOVWF TRISB
            MOVLW B'00010000'          ; Port RA4 input, others outputs
            MOVWF TRISA                 
            MOVLW H'03'                ; prescaler on TMR0 and 1:16
            MOVWF OPTION_REG
            MOVLW H'A0'                ; GIE & T0IE set T0IF cleared
            MOVWF INTCON               
            MOVLW H'F4'                ; initialize INTCNT
            MOVWF INTCNT               
            MOVLW H'06'                ; initialize FUDGE
            MOVWF FUDGE                
            CLRF OFFSET                ; initialize OFFSET
            RETURN
```

Comment: How are you checking that TRIS is changing?

Comment: It is visible in the special functions registers listing of the MPLAB simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is described in [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/35007b.pdf) section 2.2:  Data Memory Organization

> The data memory is partitioned into two areas. The first is the
>   Special Function Registers (SFR) area, while the second is the General
>   Purpose Registers (GPR) area.The SFRs control the operation of the
>   device. Portions of data memory are banked. This is for both the SFR
>   area and the GPR area.

So as you can see that SFR/GPR address is 7 bit long when we compose single CPU instruction! The 8-th bit of address is memory `Bank` selection bit and this bit is not part of single 14 bit instruction.
Check also: PIC16CXXX INSTRUCTION SET! As example you can check `DECF` instruction. It is composed from 14 bits: b'00 0011 dfff ffff' where 'd' is direction and 'fff ffff' is 7 bit address. 
To address more than 7 bits you need paging mechanism at PIC16F84 is this a single bit `RP0` stored in `STATUS` SFR. Because PIC16F84 have only 8 bit data memory address space.

Check the `PORTA` and `TRISA` 7 bit address, as you can see that is the same (0x05), but the 8th bit is different. And this bit must be set with another instruction via `RP0` bit, you are using in your example: `BSF   STATUS,RP0` instruction.

Remember MPLAB compiler dosen't know which bank is set so the both labels `PORTA` and `TRISA` are correct.

Comment: I have read it over and now if I understand correctly then setting (BCF) bank 0 and TRIS results in change of PORT. The other way around. Setting bank 1 (BSF) and using PORT results in change of TRIS.

Comment: @Decapod: exactly bacause PORTA and TRISA have the same 7 bit address.